# javascript debug in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging

I have a datepicker control that I want to debug in IE (Chrome is fine, Chrome is super!). Each time when the breakpoint is triggerred the control looses a focus. Do you know any tool/plugin etc that can keep a focus while I'm stepping over in a debugger?

Comment: Ugh, no fun. For focus debugging, sadly, one usually has to fall back on `console.log` statements (just make sure you remember to remove them when done).

Comment: Yeah, log is an option of course, I was just wander if there is a tool or plugin, that can help me.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hoping someone would know of one. But while a couple of the mobile browsers have remote debugging (which is basically what you'd need, to be able to debug from a different machine -- switching apps affects focus too), as far as I know desktop browser support for remote debugging is lagging... You might see if you can get [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html) to help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to T.J. Crowder for his comments. I found that a conditional breakpoint + trace solves my problem. That's not perfect, but does its job.